# access raspberry desktop over internet

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, vnc

I am currently trying to access my raspberry pi over the internet. I hope I can access its desktop in library when my pi is at home.

for now, I have managed to access my pi through ssh over the internet, but I don't know how to access the GUI interface. I downloaded RealVNC Viewer on my PC and use `sudo apt-get install realvnc-vnc-server realvnc-vnc-viewer` to make VNC available on my pi. the VNC viewer is now working well when I am at home that my pc and pi are in the same Wi-Fi, but it's not working when I'm in library. It gives: Connection refused by the computer.

I know the IP address of my pi and it's working when I use ssh option, can anyone shed some light on my problem? By the way, I have changed my port to, say, 30 in my sshd config file for security reason. Would it make any difference when I use vnc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two options. One is to have an X server in your client computer (in the library): Xming is good. Then use "ssh -X" from the library computer. The "-X" option does the magic to tunnel the X protocol transparently from the pi to the PC.

The other option is to use vnc, but if your pi is behind a router, you have to "open a port" on the router and forward that port toward your pi. The procedure for doing this is very different from router to router.

There are also mechanisms available, in linux/unix, to limit access from outside the internal net (/etc/hosts.***), you should check.

Comment: I have already installed Xming in my own PC, and Im using my PC in the library. I tried `ssh -X` into my pi, but it gives me this: `Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.` and `connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: No such file or directory`. Does it mean I need some extra libraries?

Comment: I don't think you need more libraries, you should check your ssh and X configuration. For example in /etc/ssh/sshd_config check "X11Forwarding yes". Also check Xming log, it could be enlightning. There is a lot to check and debug.

Comment: I have set X11forwarding to yes, but Xming is still not working. How about VNC server? Could you give me some essential features I should take care of when setting my router?

Comment: Check the outgoing port (default 5900) of your VNC client. Then go to your router admin page, and "forward" that port to the fixed IP of your PI, same port. Some router call this "port forwarding", some other "services". Basically, you say to your router: when a connection comes in, to port 5900, take the data and send them to IP 192.168.1.142 (the pi address), port 5900. Read the router manual, search internet for more info.